# Automated Builds in Team Foundation Server not generated

Tags: tfsbuild

I am trying to setup a automated build for a project in VS2010 using the TFS inbuilt trigger scheduler setting. 
TFS-->Builds-->my_Build-->Right click, Edit Build Definition.
In Trigger tab, I have Scheduled build every week on following days and given time as say 6:00 AM.

I don’t see any build getting queued at that time. Is there any other setting to be done, can you please point me to any links which has the settings please.

Thanks

Arvind

Comment: You said you don't see any build getting queued at that time -- do you mean you're looking at the items on queue after you've created your Build Definition and you don't see your new def? Try changing your build definition and set it to build like 5 mins after the current time -- and check if it actually runs successfully. Or else you'd have to wait after 6AM to know if it actually ran. You could look through its history of runs to see if it executed or not -- and whether successfully or not.

Answer (score 2):

Just a wild guess:
[image]
If you haven't checked this, your scheduled build will only start if there are changes in the sources mapped within the Workspace.

Comment: I have also selected Build even if nothing has changed, but it still does not build. Also there were changes made that day to TFS.

Comment: Then your problem can't be solved with what I'm proposing, I'm sorry.

Comment: Another thought: Can it be that your Build Server operates on a 'different' [6:00 AM] than your workstation?